# lokiJs update array in object not persisted

Tags: angularjs, lokijs

I use lokiJs for angualJS app. 
I try to update one object in collection withe an array.
But data in array was lost !

```
$scope.seance from loki , exos is internal array
$scope.seance.exos.push($scope.exo);
try{
    $scope.seances.update($scope.seance);
}catch(err){
     console.log(err);
     alert('cant update');
}
$scope.seances.commit();
db.saveDatabase();
```

Thanks a lot for your help!